# ng-option select bound to separate array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have a product model that has a property I want to bind to a separate array of options. Basically by product model has a property called 'category', like this:

```
productModel = {
  Id : 1,
  Description: 'Widget',
  Category: 0,
  ...
```

As you can see, the property is an int (from the db) but I also get a separate array of what the categories are:

```
Categories : [
  { "Number" : 0, Name : "N/A" },
  { "Number" : 1, Name : "Option 1" },
  { "Number" : 2, Name : "Option 2" }
]
```

I want to be able to have a select list with the corresponding value shown, so if the product model comes back with 0 set then the default value in the select list will be "N/A".

I have achieved this by doing:

```
<select ng-model="Categories[productModel.Category]" ng-options="v.name for v in Categories" ...
```

but the problem with this is that when I change the option the value isn't binding back to the model. Because the data is posted back the server when the user changes the value I don't really want to change the productModel to have the same Name and Number structure as the categories (I can do this if it is the best way). I really just want the user to be able to select an option and for the product model to contain the corresponding number.

Can I (should I) do this using the 'track by'?

Comment: add an `ng-change=myFunction()` and in your `$scope` implement the logic of that function that set the model variable property

Comment: Are you posting the `productModel` to the server?

Comment: Yes. When the user clicks a save button I just dump the product model back through ajax. I want it to look the same as it comes out really but I can change the model as it goes back and forth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your `ng-model` value to bind to `productModel.Category`, you also need to update your `ng-options` expression to the following `ng-options="v.Name as v.Number for v in categories"`.

You can find more information regarding the `ng-options` and `ng-model` directives [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#usage).

Please see working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tjaart/m7Legtgj/1/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
  <select ng-model="productModel.Category" ng-options="v.Name as v.Number for v in categories"></select>
  <h3>productModel.Catecogy => {{productModel.Category}}</h3>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.productModel = {
    Id: 1,
    Description: 'Widget',
    Category: 0
  };

  $scope.categories = [{
    "Number": 0,
    Name: "N/A"
  }, {
    "Number": 1,
    Name: "Option 1"
  }, {
    "Number": 2,
    Name: "Option 2"
  }];
}]);
```

Not relevant to the question but its good practice to try and keep the case of your properties and variable names the same.